# Pegando caminho absoluto a partir do relativo no Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou com um problema na leitura de arquivos em um código que está o seguinte:

**src/race.js**

```js
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import { resolve } from "path";

export function readFile(path) {
  const absolutePath = resolve(__dirname, path);
  const content = readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");

  return content;
}
```

Pois bem, quando uso ele num arquivo dentro da própria pasta `src` ele funciona:

**src/index.js**

```js
readFile("./kart.in")
// /home/pliavi/Projects/Kart/src/Kart.in
```

porém estou usando a função numa pasta `test` e quando uso esta função, ele continua apontando para o `src` ao invés do `test`:

**test/race.test**

```js
readFile("./kart.test.in")
// /home/pliavi/Projects/Kart/src/Kart.test.in
// Arquivo não encontrado, pois ele está na test, não na src
```

Como faço para que não importe qual a pasta que eu esteja, o caminho passe a ser partir da pasta do script atual?

Porque aí o `__dirname` pega o caminho do arquivo onde o `__dirname` foi escrito e não do que está sendo executado, eu quero poder usar caminhos relativos na função, pois quero usá-la em arquivos em pastas variadas, mas sem a necessidade de digitar todo o caminho a partir do `src`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma simples e funcional para o problema foi a utilização da variável `module`, a partir dela posso descobrir quem a importou e logo ter o caminho do arquivo que está sendo lido naquele instante, utilizando do seguinte:

```js
import { resolve, dirname } from "path"

const relativePath = path => resolve(dirname(module.parent.filename), path);
```

**Obs:** Existe uma única restrição, essa função não pode ser chamada no próprio arquivo, pois não terá pai e lançará um `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of null`

Isso graças a resposta e principalmente da fonte do @vitor-luiz-da-silva, consegui algumas palavras-chave que resultaram no que estava procurando, pois apesar do *StackTrace* funcionar em boa parte dos casos, ele é exagero pro que precisava e não se encaixa muito bem no contexto que queria, que era de um simples *import* ao invés de seguir o caminho do arquivo "a força", ou mesmo usar caminhos pré-definidos.

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651945/what-is-the-use-of-module-parent-in-node-js-how-can-i-refer-to-the-requireing

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir pegar o caminho absoluto do arquivo atual você pode utilizar:

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '__stack', {
get: function() {
        var orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = function(_, stack) {
            return stack;
        };
        var err = new Error;
        Error.captureStackTrace(err, arguments.callee);
        var stack = err.stack;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
        return stack;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(global, '__file', {
get: function() {
        return __stack[1].getFileName();
    }
});
```

Fonte: 
https://hk.saowen.com/a/de5f0f49d131b1fc5ae211824784134617d1d79b65e5c19d6420ac5dca423d58

Com isso em mãos, basta criar uma função para pegar a url de "__file". Uma regex seria suficiente, assim vc sempre teria a pasta atual do script sendo executado.

```
console.log("Arquivo: %s", __file);
```

**O MELHOR SERIA:**

Utilizando as variáveis "__filename" e "__dirname" você conseguirá o caminho do arquivo, assim você poderá extrair o caminho:

Você pode tentar esses scripts:

```
1. require('path').basename(__filename);
```

ou

```
2. __filename.split(path.sep).pop()
```

Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js

Uma maneira mais padronizada seria você definir uma constante definindo o caminho dos arquivos de acordo com o ambiente que você estiver. Assim quando você estiver executando em ambiente de testes buscará em uma pasta X e se estiver em ambiente de produção em uma pasta Y.

```
function getPath(){

   //Busque como utilizar variáveis de sistema para seu sistema operacional(process.env)
   var environment = process.env.MEU_AMBIENTE || "test"; 

    if(environment == "test"){
       return  "SEU CAMINHO PARA ARQUIVOS DE TEST"
     }
    else
     {
       return  "SEU CAMINHO PARA ARQUIVOS DE DEV"
     }
```

}

Se eu fosse você, começaria a definir arquivos de configuração já pensando no ambiente que vai trabalhar:

```
//Voce configura no seu sistema operacional onde seu arquivo de configuração esta
//No linux seria assim:
export ENVIRONMENT=test
export CONFIG_PATH=/etc/opt/myapp/config_folder
```

**lib/load_config.js**

```
'use strict'

var conf = require('nconf');
var configPath = process.env.CONFIG_PATH || ".";
var environment = process.env.ENVIRONMENT || "development";

//loading configuration file according with environment variables
conf.argv()
   .env()
   .file({ file: configPath + "/" + "config."+environment+".json"});

module.exports = conf;
```

**config.dev.json**

```
{
 "caminho.arquivos": "meu/caminho/de/dev"
}
```

**config.test.json**

```
{   
 "caminho.arquivos": "meu/caminho/de/test"
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
var conf = require('./lib/load_config');
var caminho = conf.get("caminho.arquivos");
```

Desta maneira, basta você mudar a variável de ambiente e terá o resultado esperado. Além do mais, poderá guardar todas as variáveis dependentes do ambiente no arquivo json, por exemplo usando as credenciais de base de dados:

**config.dev.json**

```
{
 "caminho.arquivos": "meu/caminho/de/dev",
 "database.host": "ip_do_banco_de_dados",
 "database.name": "meubanco",
 "database.usuario": "meuusuario" 
 "database.senha": "minhasenha"
...
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
/****************************** DATABASE **************************************/
var mysql = require('mysql');

var host = nconf.get('database.host');
var user = nconf.get('database.usuario');
var password = nconf.get('database.senha');
var databaseName = nconf.get('database.name');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: host,
  user: user,
  database: databaseName,
  password: password
});
```

Comment: Então é que aí o __dirname pega o caminho do arquivo onde o __dirname foi escrito e não do que está sendo executado, eu quero poder usar caminhos relativos, pois quero usar essa função em várias pastas, mas sem a necessidade de digitar todo o caminho a partir da `src` (onde está o arquivo da função) ou usar caminhos pré-definidos.

Comment: Isso que vc esta buscando é um anti-padrão, por isso está difícil de encontrar, é um pouco ilógico. Você está misturando imagens, arquivos variados e código fonte na mesma pasta em diferentes lugares.. Vou te dar uma soluçao, mas recomendo fazer o que te disse nessa primeira resposta...

Comment: Talvez seja olhando como algo de web ou uma aplicação, estou utilizando como uma lib, então não pode interessar onde o usuário vai manter os arquivos. Mas também não acho que seria uma boa fazer o usuário usar o __dirname, já consegui o resultado que queria com outras linguagens, mas não entendo como não é algo tão simples em JS. Tipo, se ver o próprio require/import fazem isso, eu só quero ler um arquivo a partir de um caminho relativo, não devia ser tão complicado.

Comment: Acabo de editar a resposta, acredito que isso possa te ajudar. Principalmente o link que deixei na fonte, eu usei para gerar um logger.

Comment: Bizarro, mas funcionou, e haha, toda vez chego com um problema, estou usando babel, ele põe o script no modo `strict` e não permite utilizar o `callee`, mas acho que consigo algum resultado a partir da sua resposta, muito obrigado por todo tempo gasto para responder! o/ Só não vou colocar como melhor resposta, pois ainda acho que exista uma forma que não seja algo próximo de uma gambiarra (sem ofender xD).

Comment: O loco, xinga mas nao ofende pow kkkk... Gambiarra nao, ajuste técnico rss ;) Para mim o que vc esta tentando fazer é uma gambi das grandes, revisa sua arquitetura porque me parece que esta fora de padrão o que vc esta tentando fazer ;)

Comment: kkkkkk, nada xD. Mas então, esse é mais pra uma coisa simples, mas bateu bem a dúvida, mas não acho ser tanta gambiarra, tu já viu no React quando tu importa uma imagem? ele usam caminho relativo a partir do arquivo do componente, praticamente o que quero fazer é uma função que faça isso, buscar um arquivo a partir do script que estou executando naquele momento, to testando umas coisas aqui, e acho que encontrei... Só vendo se não dá nenhum xabú antes de abrir a resposta